# getting css position:sticky to work with shinydashboard

Tags: css, shiny, position, shinydashboard, sticky

I can't seem to get `position:sticky` to work with shinydashboard.

Example below. I was hoping box 3 would scroll until hitting the top of the box and then remain fixed. Appreciate any ideas anyone might have.

```
#-----------------------------------#
#clear workspace and load libraries----
#-----------------------------------#
rm(list = ls())

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

#-----------------------------------#
# Define UI for application----
#-----------------------------------#

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      box(status = 'info',solidHeader = TRUE, width = 12, height = "300px",
          p("box 1")
      ),
      column(width = 6, 
             box(status = 'info',solidHeader = TRUE, width = 12, height = "1600px",
                 p("box 2")
             )
      ),#column
      column(width = 6, style = "position:sticky;top:0;",
             box(status = 'info',solidHeader = TRUE, width = 12, height = "600px",
                 p("box 3")
             )
      )
    ),#fluidRow
  )#dashboardBody
)#dashboardPage

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
}
# Run the application----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sticky` is tricky. According to [this link](https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46), a sticky element must not be alone in his parent element. And according to [this link](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-issues-with-css-position-sticky-not-working), the parent must have a `height` property and the overflowing element must have the property `overflow: visible` or must have a `height`. Here the overflowing element is a `div.wrapper`. This works:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

#-----------------------------------#
# Define UI for application----
#-----------------------------------#

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(
        "#hhh {position: sticky; top: 0;}
        .wrapper {overflow: visible;}"
      ))
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
      box(status = 'info',solidHeader = TRUE, width = 12, height = "300px",
          p("box 1")
      ),
      column(width = 6, 
             box(status = 'info',solidHeader = TRUE, width = 12, height = "1600px",
                 p("box 2")
             )
      ),#column
      column(width = 6, 
               box(status = 'info',solidHeader = TRUE, width = 12, height = "600px",
                   tags$main(
                     style = "height: 400px;",
                     tags$header(id="hhh", "BOX 3"),
                     tags$div("contents"),
                     tags$footer("footer")
                   )
               )
      )
    ),#fluidRow
  )#dashboardBody
)#dashboardPage

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
}
# Run the application----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This does work. You deserve bonus credit for "sticky is tricky." Thanks so much, your answer not only taught me something new but inspired me to do more research on sticky, the overflow property, and wrappers.